# What was the motivation of using the optical model in Nuclear reactions (except absorption)?

Tags: nuclear-physics

One of the reasons for using the optical model in nuclear physics is to describe the elastic scattering presence of absorption. However, after going through a few books, I have the vague idea this was not the historical motivation for using a complex potential. It was probably to explain "broad resonances" or something like that. I don't have a clear picture. Can somebody give a summary of what was the state of affairs which motivated the optical (or cloudy crystal ball) model? What was meant by broad resonances? Why were they problematic? What were they trying to explain apart from absorption?

Comment: Somebody wrote a detailed answer which is now deleted. Please post is again if possible.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick search on Google the cloudy crystal ball model was motivated by the fact that neutron beams can be absorbed, scattered or diffracted by atomic nuclei
(Britannica encyclopedia).
The term broad resonances I would guess refers to the nucleons in the atomic nuclei vibrating with a large amplitude after interacting with a neutron beam,for example.